# Trying to make my own "kernel" for convolution but getting "Error: Assertion failed" in OpenCV in C++

Tags: opencv, image-processing, iteration, c++17

## General Description:

With a gray scale PNG with transparency as a height-map/input, the steps are:

1. iterate through the pixels with `.forEach()`
2. calculate the values of neighbouring pixels and add to vector array
3. use their values for some calculations
4. write the output to corresponding pixel in a different image.

My current goal is to scan pixel by pixel through an image, add all surrounding pixels to an array, then average their values. I know this is just a blur() function which already exists. But It's purely a base for a more complex function in the future (filter2D() wouldn't work either).

(In the future I'm going to apply my own vector arithmetic to each neighbouring value to find the direction a slope is facing on the height map. For this I want the pixel values in an array/vector)

## My Problem:

The problem I face is caused when I use any of the methods:

- `image.at()`
- `elemSize()`
- `sizeof()`

All means I've tried using to access the values of surrounding pixels from an image usually result in the following error being spammed in the terminal thousands of times:

1. `OpenCV(4.6.0) Error: Assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\Program Files\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 984`

or less often

2. `OpenCV(4.6.0) Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\Program Files\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 899`

My understanding is that I'm using the incorrect data types.

---

## How I import images

```
// depth_img is a heightmap with transparency, there are several ways to approach using it. 
// e.g. seperating it into two img objects, one being a transparency mask, and the other a grayscale heightmap
Mat depth_img;
depth_img = cv::imread("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Projects/image_processing/small.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::copyMakeBorder(depth_img, depth_img, 1,1,1,1, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
```

**What I've Tried:**
Iterating through the image and neighbouring pixels in different ways, including purely with for loops and indexing. And by using `.forEach()` + mapping. Both work for iterating over each pixel and I can do basic operations with this, but returning the values from neighbouring pixels is what breaks.

Here's an example of how I have been iterating through neighbouring pixels, given the row and col index of the current one:

*This is a snippet of the function used inside an image.forEach() loop, used to add neighbouring pixels values to an array. (Image is gray scale PNG but with 4 channels. The BGR values are equal. I didn't use the cv color convert method)*

```
// Define the neighbours array
vector<vector<int>> neighbours = {
    {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1},
    {-1,  0},          {1,  0},
    {-1,  1}, {0,  1}, {1,  1}
};

vector<uint8_t> neighbour_values;
cv::Vec4b pixel_value;

// Iterate through neighbouring pixels
for (vector<int> offset : neighbours)
{
    int col_i = col + offset[0];
    int row_i = row + offset[1];
    pixel_value = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(row_i, col_i);
    neighbour_values.push_back(pixel_value[0]);
}
```

`<cv::Vec4b>` in `pixel_value = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(row_i, col_i);` is where I suspect my errors occur, I believe the data type is the cause of the break because if I change it I get different errors:

I believe I should be using Vec4b because my image has transparency. Though currently With Vec4b I get the second error I pasted earlier.
In the case I use Vec3b (or any random datatype such as char or int) I get the first error.

Another suggestion I've heard is that the indexing is incorrect, but if so I fail to see how.

I'm failing to understand how I should approach collecting the values of neighbouring pixels, as well as how to set the value of an output pixel correctly. So any and everyone's input to my question would be greatly appreciated.

```
case_1 = someone could help me solve the error
case_2 = suggest a different approach to the problem which avoids it entirely
if (case_1 || case_2)
{
  user.brownie_points += 1000 
}
```

Comment: `Vec4b` assumes uint8 pixels. PNG files can contain other bit depths too, a 12 or 16-bit PNG would correspond to `Vec4w`.